# app release build issue for iphone

Tags: iphone

just one query , i run the code via release mode since i am about to launch the app ,

i can see these info when i clikc on build result

```
Validate build/Release-iphoneos/abc.app
cd /Users/applefan/Desktop/ssabc/Code/DatabaseTest
setenv PATH "/Developer/xcode3.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/xcode3.2/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Developer/xcode3.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/applefan/Desktop/hj/Code/DatabaseTest/build/Release-iphoneos/as.app

CodeSign build/Release-iphoneos/abc.app
cd /Users/applefan/Desktop/ssabc/Code/DatabaseTest
setenv IGNORE_CODESIGN_ALLOCATE_RADAR_7181968 /Developer/xcode3.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
setenv PATH "/Developer/xcode3.2/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/xcode3.2/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: aa LTD." --resource-rules=/Users/applefan/Desktop/ssabc/Code/DatabaseTest/build/Release-iphoneos/abc.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/applefan/Desktop/ssabc/Code/DatabaseTest/build/DatabaseTest.build/Release-iphoneos/abc.build/abc.xcent /Users/applefan/Desktop/ssabc/Code/DatabaseTest/build/Release-iphoneos/abc.app
```

**and this release mode is working on my iphone , i have heard that you cant run the release file with release profile**

so does that mean my app is alright and i can upload app without any issues to app store???
anything else needed to do the last checking  since this is my 1st app so i dont want them to reject

plz suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to double check, Build and Archive your app.  Then go into Organizer and then to the Archives section.  Click on your new archive and click on the Validate button.  It will then sign your code and validate it with Apple.  If it passes validation, you should be good to submit!

Comment: thanks , when i click on validate app , it ask itune username and passwd, but after that nothing happens ??

Comment: Have you added your app to iTunes Connect?

Comment: not  yet , will do tomorrow , so what should be the process?? if i upload app to itune connect , it will say upload received and then waiting for review , so how to do validate checking before submission??

Comment: @wayane can you please  explain??

Comment: Once you have 'created' the app in iTunes connect and it is in the state of waiting for the binary, you can go through the steps I outlined above to 'validate' it.  You can then submit it through organizer, or through Application Loader.